# working with IdHTTPProxyServer1

Tags: c++builder, indy, http-proxy

I want to write a simple proxy with `TIdHTTPProxyServer` and this is my code :

```
void __fastcall TForm1::FormCreate(TObject *Sender)
{
    IdHTTPProxyServer1->DefaultPort = 8090;
    IdHTTPProxyServer1->Active = true;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormClose(TObject *Sender, TCloseAction &Action)
{
    int Index = 0;
    TList * cList;
    {
        cList = IdHTTPProxyServer1->Contexts->LockList();
        try
        {
            for ( int stop = cList->Count - 1, Index = 0; Index <= stop; Index++)
            {
                TIdContext * t;
                t = static_cast <TIdContext*>(cList[Index]);
                t->Connection->Disconnect();
            }
        }
        __finally
        {
            IdHTTPProxyServer1->Contexts->UnlockList();
        }
        IdHTTPProxyServer1->Active = false;
    }
}
```

I have two Question :

1. How can I cast a TList to a TIdContext?
2. This code doesn't change my IP and I want to change my IP.  How can I change my IP with `TIdHTTPProxyServer` ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is a Q&A site.  Your question is much too broad to be answered.  Please be more specific.  What exactly do you want to do with `TIdHTTPServer`?  What have you tried so far?  What is not working for you?

Comment: You have asked two separate questions.  They need to be posted separately.  Please read StackOverflow's rules before you ask any further questions.  I have answered the first question here regarding `TList` usage.  Please post a separate question for the second one regarding your IP usage, and explain in more detail exactly what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I cast a TList to a TIdContext?

You don't, as they are not related classes.  The real problem is that you are not accessing the `TList` items correctly to begin with.  You need to use the `TList::Items[]` property instead, either directly:

```
t = static_cast<TIdContext*>(cList->Items[Index]);
```

Or indirectly, by dereferencing the `TList` pointer so that `TList::operator[]` (which uses the `Items[]` property internally) can be invoked:

```
t = static_cast<TIdContext*>((*cList)[Index]);
```

Either way, this code is completely unnecessary, as Indy will automatically close all active clients for you when the server is deactivated/destroyed:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::FormClose(TObject *Sender, TCloseAction &Action)
{
    IdHTTPProxyServer1->Active = false;
}
```

> This code doesn't change my IP and I want to change my IP. How can I change my IP with TIdHTTPProxyServer ?

You cannot change the local machine's IP with `TIdHTTPProxyServer`, that is not it is meant for.  In fact, there is nothing in Indy to change the local machine's IP, that is outside of Indy's scope.  You have to use platform-specific APIs for that instead.  What are you trying to accomplish exactly?  Please post a separate question about this topic, and explain your requirements for it.

Comment: Your  responses solved my problem.

my second question was just an idea.
I'm new to Indy and RAD Studio and just wanted to know that I can change my IP with `TIdHTTPProxyServer` or not which I got my answer.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What made you think that `TIdHTTPProxyServer` could change your IP?

Comment: filtering and proxies.
As I told, that was just an idea and a question.
I wanted to know can I brake filtering with `HttpProxyServe` or not.